# javaScript why using function inside empty function

Tags: javascript

in this code

```
function adjustStyle() {
    var width = 0;
    // get the width.. more cross-browser issues
    if (window.innerHeight) {
        width = window.innerWidth;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if (document.body) {
        width = document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    // now we should have it
    if (width < 600) {
        document.getElementById("myCSS").setAttribute("href", "_css/narrow.css");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myCSS").setAttribute("href", "_css/main.css");
    }
}

// now call it when the window is resized.
window.onresize = function () {
    adjustStyle();
};
```

why I have to use adjustStyle() inside empty function 
why I can not used like window.onresize = adjustStyle();

Comment: `window.onresize = adjustStyle` would absolutely work. Just make sure you don't put the parenthases after

Comment: instead of calling you just set the function definition `window.onresize=adjustStyle`

Comment: Initializing function to variable...Its one of those design patterns in javascript.

Comment: If you use an event listener, you can just pass the reference.

Comment: It is working  thankssss

Answer (score 2):

You could call :

```
window.onresize = adjustStyle;
```

Declaring `adjustStyle` like :

```
var adjustStyle = function() { [...] };
```

or

```
function adjustStyle() { [...] }
```

Answer (score 1):

> why I have to use adjustStyle() inside empty function why I can not used like window.onresize = adjustStyle();

Because if you did that, `onresize` would be assigned the *result* of calling the function - which is undefined - and therefore nothing would happen. You could however do this:

```
window.onresize = adjustStyle; // note no parentheses
```

Which would set resize to the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

because with a function you can call several handlers after resize.

e.g.:

```
window.onresize = function(){
  doOneThing();
  doAnotherThing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I felt like the other answers got it right, but didn't explain what JavaScript does when you do

```
window.onresize = adjustStyle();
```

On runtime, this will bind whatever the `adjustStyle();` function **RETURNS** to the window.onresize event, not the function itself. It will run it once and bind the return value to the onresize event.

So if you catch the return value of `adjustStyle();` into a variable, like so:

```
var adjust = adjustStyle();
```

and log the `adjust` variable, you'll see that the it logs `undefined`, because your function does not **return** anything.

If you would end your `adjustStyle();` function with `return 'hello';` for example. The above would log `'hello'`. It is what the function **returns**.

So opposed to binding `window.onresize` to `adjustStyles();`, you can bind it to `adjustStyles` without the parenthesis. Like so

```
window.onresize = adjustStyles;
```

This binds the `function` reference to the onresize event, so not what it **returns** but what it **references** (a function you defined).
You can skip your own function definition, like so, resulting in the same

```
window.onresize = function(){/..your code../};
```

This will bind the function directly to the onresize event, instead of having a **references** to it through the variable `adjustStyles`;

Comment: `I  felt like the other answers got it right, but didn't explain what JavaScript does when you do` - except that was my very first sentence.

Comment: @Jamiec, yes, you've explained what I explain in 1 sentence, but seeing as OP is clearly new to JavaScript, wouldn't it makes sense to explain what is interpreted step-by-step?  You've given the answer for this particular `problem`, I feel explaining what happens step-by-step is far more productive for OP and future readers. Understanding the core > fixing a specific problem.

Comment: Perfect answer, Thanks